# The chain rule: differentiation in several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

Hi! I am trying to study for an upcoming exam by doing online problems, but this one has me completely stumped. If someone can help answer or explain how to do this problem I would really appreciate it.

Comment: well, do you know the chain rule? state it and tell us at which point exactly you're stuck. if it helps $x(r,s) = r^8 + s^8$

Comment: well, first i started by finding the partial derivative of x and came up with 7cos(y). Then I found the partial derivative of y to be -7xsin(y). then I obtained the partial derivative of x/partial derivative of s to be 8s^7, the partial derivative of y/partial derivative of s to be -11, the partial derivative of x/parital derivative of r to be 8r^7, and the partial derivative of y/prtial derivative of r to be 11. After that i did not know what to do with that information. I am not sure what formal to use or how to move on from here.

Comment: "Well, do you know the chain rule?".

It seems you have everything you need to find what you need. According to the chain rule, $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}}$

Comment: you've pretty much done all that's necessary. now all you need to do is to plug it into the chain rule - if you don't remember its statement then just look it up on wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: so ∂f/∂s = 7cos(y)(8s^7)+(-7xsin(y)(-11), but how do i solve this now for ∂f/∂s of (r,s)=(2,1)?

Comment: If you know the values of $r$ and $s$ you can find the values of $x,y$, can't you?.

Comment: Or you could just simply replace the given values (or equations, must I say) of x and y.

Comment: @Miguelgondu that is not an intention of the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $s$ as follows

$$\begin{align} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}f(x,y) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \\&= 7\cos(y)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} - 7x\sin(y)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \\&= 7(8s^7)\cos(y) + 77x\sin(y) \\&= 56s^7\cos(11r - 11s) + 77(r^8 + s^8)\sin(11r - 11s) \,\,. \end{align}$$
Now substitute the point $(r,s) = (2,1)$ to complete the calculation.